# How to install caffe with python3 on Google Colab Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, caffe

I am trying to install caffe on Google Colab.

`!apt install caffe-cuda` installs.

But in the next line when I type `import caffe`, it doesn't work. This error comes  :

```
<ipython-input-8-a0183e542e82> in <module>()
      5 
      6 import sys
----> 7 import caffe

1 frames

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/caffe/pycaffe.py in <module>()
     11 import numpy as np
     12 
---> 13 from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, \
     14         RMSPropSolver, AdaDeltaSolver, AdamSolver, NCCL, Timer
     15 import caffe.io

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'caffe._caffe'
```

Dont understand why this is happening.

Comment: Did you found a solution ?